# When are fixtures in conftest loaded?

Tags: pytest

I have a lot of data loading from filesystem in my conftest. They are loaded at the beginning of every unit-test. But obviously not every unit-test needs all of those data. I am thinking of creating individual fixtures to load separated data. But that will be useful only if fixtures from conftest.py are loaded on-demand basis.

So, does conftest.py load all fixtures at start-up or only when needed?

Comment: If by "loaded" you mean "executed" - fixtures are executed only if referenced in a test (or another referenced fixture) or if they have set `autouse=True`. The fixture definitions are loaded on startup, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Right, by "loaded" I meant "executed". We are only using for data-loading, therefore I used the ambiguous word.